# How to append to a list which have more than 2 columns

Tags: python, list, append

I am creating a program in which I have to scrape 2 columns one by one. I am not able to append the list which has two columns.
For example:

```
    >>> list1[['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
    >>> list1[0][2]
    ... 'a3'
    >>> list1[0][2]+="Ratan"
    >>> list1[0][2]
    ... 'a3Ratan'
    >>> list2 = [["Ratan",[]],["Kanchan",[]]]
    >>> list2
    ... [['Ratan', []], ['Kanchan', []]]
    >>> list2[0][1]+=" Bhushan"
    >>> list2[0][1]
    ... [' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n']
    >>> list2
    ... [['Ratan', [' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n']],['Kanchan',[]]]
    >>> list2[0][1]+=' Bhushan'
    >>> list2
    ... [['Ratan', [' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n']], ['Kanchan', []]]
    >>> list2[0][1]+=str(' Bhushan')
    >>> list2[0][1]
    ... [' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'B', 'h', 'u', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n']
```

I do not understand why string concatenation is not working.

Please help.

Comment: *"I have to scrape 2 columns one by one for which I am not able to append the list which has two columns"*. You what?

Comment: `+=` corresponds to `extend`, not `append`. Do `list2[0][1]+=[" Bhushan"]` or `list2[0][1].append(" Bhushan")` instead

Comment: It worked man.... just awesome...

Comment: the problem is initialisation,`'' + 'Bhushan'`  != `j=[]; j+='Bhushan'`

Comment: I am making a spider which scrapes the data from website. first it gets the links in "A" tag. Then it gets the image "SRC". It appends the list one by one. But the suggested line is not working in code.

Answer (score 2):

`list1[0][2]` is a string, `list2[0][1]` is a list. The difference is how they handle the `+=` operator:

```
a = 'b'
a += 'bcd'  # appends 
# 'abcd'

a = ['a']
a += 'bcd'  # extends the list by the iterable (string is iterable!)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you want to append an element to a list, use `append`:

```
a.append('bcd')
# ['a', 'bcd']
```